# CMD EnableDelayedExpansion and exclamation mark inside variable

Tags: loops, variables, cmd

i try read commands from ttt.txt file and then run them in loop

"my program.exe" is a winrar SFX archive, -d is destination path parameter. Problem is what if DestinationDir varibale contain special characters like "!" exclamation mark

i tried to replace ! with ^! , destination path then contains ! but also ^ char.

ttt.txt

```
md "Some folder"
"c:\tmp\my program.exe" -d!DestinationDir!
md "myNewDir"
...
another commands
```

example:
Execute.bat "C:\new Folder [!!!$#,;]path\" "Test"

Execute.bat

```
@echo off

set "DestinationDir=%1"
set "MenuGroupDir=%2"

@echo par1=%DestinationDir%
SET DestinationDir="%DestinationDir:!=^!%"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

@echo DestinationDir= %DestinationDir% !DestinationDir!



IF exist %DestinationDir% IF [%MenuGroupDir%] NEQ [] (
    @echo destination-dir=%DestinationDir%
    @echo menugroup-dir=%MenuGroupDir%
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%G IN ("ttt.txt") DO  (
    %%G
    )

    )
) ELSE (
    @echo DestinationDir=%DestinationDir%
    @echo MenuGroupDir=%MenuGroupDir%
    @echo.
    @echo Usage:
    @echo Parameter1 must be Destination (Dir must Exist)
    @echo Parameter2 must be MenuGroup Dir
)

pause
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't use `delayed expansion` so you can remove the statement that enables it.  You also have `unbalanced parentheses`.

Comment: I cant remove delayed expansion because it is used in loop, line 2 in ttt.txt

Comment: Line 2 can use percent signs and remove this line `SET DestinationDir="%DestinationDir:!=^!%"` too

Comment: can but not in loop %%G executes line 2 "c:\tmp\my program.exe" -d!DestinationDir!

Comment: Line 2 can use percent signs

Comment: if i use this in line 2 "c:\tmp\my program.exe" -d%DestinationDir%, path in SFX "my program.exe" is %DestinationDir% and not contained text of variable

Comment: I see, yes, you may be able to use `call %%G` in the for loop depending on what is in `ttt.txt` while using percent as I outlined.

Comment: it not so easy because if %%G contains someTEXT!texttext! it it will cut of every ! also text inside !! so result value is: someTEXT

Comment: The `!` issue is because of the delayed expansion.  Do everything I've suggested in my comments.